# Websphere portal Search portlet pagination

Tags: websphere-portal

Is there a way to increase the results of the Content Sources displayed.

For now only 5 Content Sources could be viewed at a time. We have 1300 means 277 pages. To find a Crawler I have to navigate the damn slow 277 pages. Me and my team is banging head hard to find a solution. We tried to find something in SearchAdmin.war, nothing relevant is found in that also. There should be an option to increase the number of Content Sources in a collection to be viewed. Like 100, 50. Or whatever. Please if someone know out there HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone faces the same problem. They can follow these steps.
Working on Portal 8. Please take relevant backups before doing anything in production :)

```
-> /IBM/WebSphere/PortalServer/search/wp.search.admin/installableApps
-> Copy to local SearchAdmin.war
-> Extract SearchAdmin.war
-> Edit SearchAdmin\jsp\html\ManageContentProviders.jsp
-> go to this line (rowsPerPage="5") < Change 5 to what ever value you want.
-> Login to portal console
-> Navigate to WebModules
-> Search for SearchAdmin and update with the modified .war
```

Restart not required. :)